# Problem in converting MS-SQL Query to spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert this basic SQL Query in Spark

```
select Grade, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()
from StudentGrades
group by Grade
```

I have tried using windowing functions in spark like this

```
val windowSpec = Window.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)

df1.select(
$"Arrest"
).groupBy($"Arrest").agg(sum(count("*")) over windowSpec,count("*")).show()


+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------+--------+
|Arrest|sum(count(1)) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED 
FOLLOWING)|count(1)|
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------+--------+
|  true|                                                                        
665517|  184964|
| false|                                                                        
665517|  480553|
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

But when I try dividing by count(*) it through's error

```
df1.select(
$"Arrest"
).groupBy($"Arrest").agg(count("*")/sum(count("*")) over 
windowSpec,count("*")).show()
```

**It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.;;**

My Question is when I'm already using count() inside sum() in the first query I'm not receiving any errors of using an aggregate function inside another aggregate function but why get error in the second one?

Comment: Functionally you want? Please provide input and expected output, snall will suffice.

Comment: this line `count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()` basically will calculate percentage in SQL, that is what I wanted to achieve. I have already got the output by first getting the total count in a variable and then using that to divide the individual count, but I just wanted to know how to write a similar query in spark SQL.

Comment: You mean percentage of total?

Comment: yes the output should be like
`count   | percentage
184964 | 27.79
480553 | 72.21`

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
   ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)
    )).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2")

val df2 = df
  .groupBy("c1")
  .agg(sum("Val1").alias("sum"))
  .withColumn("fraction", col("sum") /  sum("sum").over())

df2.show
```

You will need to tailor to your own situation. E.g. count instead of sum. As follows:

```
val df2 = df
  .groupBy("c1")
  .agg(count("*"))
  .withColumn("fraction", col("count(1)") /  sum("count(1)").over())
```

returning:

```
+---+--------+-------------------+
| c1|count(1)|           fraction|
+---+--------+-------------------+
|  E|       1|0.16666666666666666|
|  B|       1|0.16666666666666666|
|  D|       1|0.16666666666666666|
|  C|       1|0.16666666666666666|
|  A|       2| 0.3333333333333333|
+---+--------+-------------------+
```

You can do x 100. I note the alias does not seem to work as per the sum, so worked around this and left comparison above. Again, you will need to tailor to your specifics, this is part of my general modules for research and such.